# References on the (reflected) Bessel process: construction, formulas, densities, properties

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

In order to get a feeling for the reflected Bessel process the script [[1]](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Elawler/bessel18new.pdf) is a really nice resource.

Nevertheless, I feel a reluctance to use it as a reference, since

- it is not an official and "for all time" available publication, and may be altered in the future
- due to its conciseness it has a lack of details
- it is somehow inconvient for me to navigate through it

The points I am interested in are:

1. generally a construction and definition of the reflected Bessel process, see p.29 of [[1]](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Elawler/bessel18new.pdf)
2. the transition density, see p.29, eq. (36) of [[1]](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Elawler/bessel18new.pdf),
3. for which parameters the process hits zero, see p.6, Proposition 2.1 of [[1]](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Elawler/bessel18new.pdf)
4. that it is strong Markov, has continuous paths and solves a SDE up to the first hitting time of zero

References for the different bullet points can be found in various places, but I found them nowhere together, and especially for Bessel processes in one place except in [[1]](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Elawler/bessel18new.pdf). For example:

- one can find corresponding statements regarding 1. and 3.,4. about the squared Bessel process in the blog [[2]](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/07/28/bessel-processes/)
- regarding 3.,4. it is also possible to view the process more generally as diffusion in an interval and apply Feller's Test for Explosions, see p.342 in [3]
- in fact, regarding 2., for me it is only relevant, that the process has a density w.r.t. Lebesgue measure. maybe more general situations as in this post [Is the distribution of an Ito diffusion at time t absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072086/is-the-distribution-of-an-ito-diffusion-at-time-t-absolutely-continuous-wrt-lebe?rq=1) also work here

**Question** : Is there a book or monograph giving all these properties and more details?

[[1] http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~lawler/bessel18new.pdf](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Elawler/bessel18new.pdf)

[[2] https://almostsuremath.com/2010/07/28/bessel-processes/](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/07/28/bessel-processes/)

[3] Karatzas, Shreve - Brownian motion and stochastic calculus